# C# Selenium solving google ReCaptcha, iFrame issues

Tags: c#, selenium, recaptcha

currently, I automate some processes using selenium and need to solve Google ReCaptcha.
The technology used to solve the ReCaptcha is the browser, Plugin Buster.
I enter the Google ReCaptcha using the following

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("recaptcha-anchor")).Click();
```

Now I switch back to the default Frame using:

```
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Now I try to enter the Google ReCaptcha Menu Frame and click the Buster icon, using the following code.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(Indexoftheframetoenter);
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#solver-button")).Click();
```

[Icon to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i479h.png)

The problem with that is, the index seems to be a random lower number, which causes my code not to click the icon. I managed to "solve" this issue with ugly try and catch blocks, covering a specific amount of numbers. I am not familiar with iFrame. Is there a way to guess this specific iFrame?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Update. It helped me to write down what I wanted.
Noticed you can also enter iFrames using their names. I leave this here for the community.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("recaptcha challenge");
```

Answer (score 0):

Google detects that it is a bot and does not perform the audio captcha, so this method will be of little use to you via selenium

Comment: Hey Iban, yes that is correct. ReCaptcha will detect normal selenium versions. Before I took a look at ReCaptcha, I worked on automating websites protected by Distil Networks. After a lot of work, I managed to get it working. Google ReCaptcha isn't complaining about my automation right now. I think my patches also apply for it.

Comment: @0x0000000 What were your patches?